# Uploading images to firebase storage using Kotlin not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm currently using Kotlin to upload images. I followed the documentation and I'm currently logged in as an authenticated user.

Here is my code:

```
storage = Firebase.storage
private fun uploadImageTest() {
    val storageRef = storage.reference
    val imagesRef = storageRef.child("images/${UUID.randomUUID()}")
    val uploadTask = imagesRef.putFile(imageURI)

    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {

    }.addOnSuccessListener {

    }
}
```

But when I run the code, the error I get is:

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/drop-calendar.appspot.com/o
    java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

I have already tried changing rules to no authentication needed and even tried code of my friend which does work, but not on mine. When I open the provided link, I get this json :

```
error: { code: 403, message: "permission denied. could not perform this operation" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your application in firebase console -> Storage -> Rules and check your settings there. If it contains something like:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

then it means that your users have to be authorized to perform certain operations. You can either add authentication to your app (check https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) or just allow read access to your storage to any request:

```
allow read;
allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
```

For more information regarding security rules you can check here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security

Comment: i fixed it already, i had my auth == null, but i was always an logged in user haha. And i also needed to reinstall the app on the emulator for some reason. Thanks tho!